# cannot resolve symbol REQUEST_PERMISSIONS and myMethod() in android studio this is my code

Tags: android

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity1.this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) + ContextCompat
                .checkSelfPermission(MainActivity1.this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                    (MainActivity1.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ||
                    ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                            (MainActivity1.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                        "Please Grant Permissions",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("ENABLE",
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity1.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission
                                                .WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                                        **REQUEST_PERMISSIONS**);
                            }
                        }).show();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity1.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission
                                .WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                        **REQUEST_PERMISSIONS**);
            }
        } else {
            //Call whatever you want
            **myMethod();**
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
That is the request code you need to pass to the request permisson method,
once user grants/deny the permissions,call back method 
onRequestPermissionsResult will be called with permission result.  

  public static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 100;//Any integer


   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity1.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission .WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
     Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);

 @Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, 
    @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults.length > 0
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS) {
        goToCamera(null);
    } else {
        // permission denied, boo! Disable the
        // functionality that depends on this permission.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**REQUEST_PERMISSIONS** is an integer value that specifies your request code for some permission. Write following line at the top your activity.

```
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS=1232;//This can be any integer value and field name can also be changed
```